# Material UI Grid remove vertical alignment, keep order (so that pressing tab still works)

Tags: css, material-ui

Using Material-UI's standard grid system,
the starting position of a new grid item after all 12 "space units" are used is determined by the longest element inside those 12 "space units".
How can I break that kind of alignment?
In [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-pwm7u?file=/demo.tsx) you see what I mean - I want the last box to start right beneath the first left box, instead of being vertically aligned to the longest item (which is the right box)

**Edit:** The order of the boxes cannot change. This is a simplified version of the real code. If I change the order of the boxes, the order when pressing the tab key changes. But I want tab to jump from Box1 to Box2 (all Boxes are components which contain various input fields)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to put the box 3 inside the same Grid as box 1

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-26rt9)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I updated my post - If I do as suggested, the tab-order is mixed up. That is why I need to keep the order of the boxes

Comment: can't you set `tabindex` manually? I might be wrong

Comment: that would be like creating 30, and when the order changes a lot of adjustments have to be made

Comment: I hope you found a way. But I came across something and remembered your issue. Could this help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-self